# Ruby On Rails : Empty array but data in SQL

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I've this models inmy code:

`car.rb`, `model.rb`, `brand.rb`

```
car belongs_to model
model belongs_to brand
```

I do this request :

```
select('brands.label, brands.id, count(ads.model_id) AS nbr_car').order('nbr_car DESC').joins(:model).joins('INNER JOIN brands AS brands ON brands.id = models.brand_id').group('brands.id').published.map{|c| [c.label, c.id]}
```

Which results in follwing SQL :

```
SELECT brands.label, brands.id, count(ads.model_id) AS nbr_car 
FROM `ads` 
INNER JOIN `models` ON `models`.`id` = `ads`.`model_id` 
INNER JOIN brands AS brands ON brands.id = models.brand_id 
WHERE `ads`.`type` IN ('Car') 
GROUP BY brands.id 
ORDER BY nbr_car DESC
```

In rails, I am getting empty array, but from SQL I am getting results!

What is wrong?

Comment: Are you sure you are running those against the same database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the culprit can be `published` here, for which I could not found any counterpart in you SQL query. Try to print result of following query:

```
select('brands.label, brands.id, count(ads.model_id) AS nbr_car').
order('nbr_car DESC').joins(:model).joins('INNER JOIN brands AS brands ON brands.id = models.brand_id').
group('brands.id')
```